# Django: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing using django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am writing a logic that would allow me to display all the quizzes that a teacher has created from the database, now I want to make this more precise by only showing a student a quiz based on the courses they enrolled in, I am trying to write this filter and it not working as expected.

models.py

```py
class Course(models.Model):
    course_creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="quiz_user")
    course_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class UserCourse(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , null = False , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course , null = False , on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="usercourse")
    payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=PAYMENT_STATUS, default="pending")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Quiz(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="quiz_user")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```py
def StudentQuizList(request):

    user_course = UserCourse.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    quizzes = Quiz.objects.filter()

    context = {
            # 'user_course': user_course,
            'quizzes': quizzes,
    }
    return render(request, 'student_dashboard/quiz.html', context)
```

error

```
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
```

quiz.html

```
{% for quiz in quizzes %}
       <img src="{{quiz.course.course_thumbnail.url}}" class="rounded-2" alt="Card image" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; object-fit: cover;">
      <h3 class="card-title"><a href'#'>{{quiz.course.course_title|title|truncatechars:30}}</a></h3>
        
        <span class="mb-0">{{quiz.title}}</span> 
        <span class="small d-block mt-1">({{quiz.questions_count}} Question{{quiz.questions_count|pluralize:"s"}})</span>
        <a href="{% url 'student_dashboard:take_quiz' quiz.course.slug quiz.slug %}" class="btn btn-warning-soft">Start Exam</a>
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dashboard, name="student_dashboard"),
    path('quiz/', StudentQuizList, name="student-quiz"),
    path('quiz/<slug:course_slug>/<slug:quiz_slug>/', take_quiz, name='take_quiz'),        

    path('quiz/<slug:course_slug>/<slug:quiz_slug>/studentresults/', QuizResultsView, name='student_quiz_results'),
    path('taken/', TakenQuizListView.as_view(), name='taken_quiz_list'),


]
```

Comment: Can you share the full traceback

Comment: Can you explain more clear about what kind of queryset do you exactly want?

Comment: @SunderamDubey I want to display only quiz related to a course that is in the usercourse, that is, I don't want to show all the quiz to a student, but only the quiz that is related to the course they are enrolled in, which is stored in the model `UserCourse`

Comment: @DestinyFranks Do you mean you want a queryset which shows all the quizzes related to a single course selected by a single logged in user?

Comment: @SunderamDubey yes that is almost what i want, i want all the queryset which shows all the quizzes related to a course that a user is enrolled into, which is stored in `UserCourse` Model.

Comment: @DestinyFranks I understood, what you said, but for queryset which will show all the quizzes related to a course in which the current logged in user enrolled in, you have to pass some pk or any slug from template file for a  single course  to show data related to that particular course in the frontend. Can you share your template file and urls.py, and also that template file in which the quizzes will show?

Comment: Okay, the question have been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass some conditions in the filter function. For example, the following queryset finds the quizzes whose course's user equals to the `request.user`.

```
quizzes = Quiz.objects.filter(course__course_creator = request.user)
```

Comment: It will be `filter(course__course_creator=request.user)`.

Comment: @SunderamDubey thanks for your response, i am not trying to list out quiz  based on courses that the logged in user created. BUT what i want is this: A user enrolled in a course, then i want to show them the `quiz`  that is created based on that course they enrolled into.